# Trying to Rename the computer. But Script failed to call depth overflow

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function to rename a computer. Following is the Script:

```
 #region Download-GitRepositories
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        This function will rename the computer to hardware serial number.


    .EXAMPLE
        Rename-Machine

#>
function Rename-Machine
{


$env:SerialNumber = "0001"
$newname = $env:SerialNumber
$oldname = $env:COMPUTERNAME

#Renamer the Computer.
$localcredential = Get-Credential
Rename-Computer –ComputerName $oldname –NewName $newname -LocalCredential $localcredential


}
```

When i call the function by running Rename-Machine command, it gives the error saying :

```
The script failed due to call depth overflow.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CallDepthOverflow
```

What i am doing wrong? i cant seem to find any recursive calls in the script to get call depth overflow error.

Comment: Are you calling the function from within the same script?  Is there anything else that goes with it, any logic at all?  If there is anything else, could you post everything?

Comment: This function is inside a powershell module. And i am not calling this function within the same script. I would be getting the $env:serialNumber variable's value from the previous function that i will run before running this function. But for the sake of testing i have hardcoded it for now.

Comment: If i isolate this function from the module and run it in a new virtual machine its working. Maybe the issue is with the other functions in the module causing the call depth overflow error

Comment: Yeah, I also isolated just the function and had success.  Definitely something upstream of that.

Comment: Issue is because you are calling recursively beyond the maximum permitted call depth. The original function has limitations..